# Qml type language parser in node js

Tags: node.js, regex, parsing

OK lets say I have a component which is very similar to qml. I'm looping over each line using nodejs and I will parse everything into a json tree. What would be the best way to parse this into a json object that has the same levels of children within children etc.

Here is an example of the code I'd like to parse:

```
Rectangle {
    id: anId

    Row {
        id: row
        backgroundColor: blue

        Image {
            id: img
            source: 'http://localhost/path'
        }

        Column {
            id: col

            Text { text: 'example 1' }

            Text { 
                text: 'example 2' 
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: btn;
        anchors: {
            top: row.bottom;
            left: parent.left;
            right: parent.right;
        }
        text: 'A Button'
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of the code I'm starting out with.

```ts
private parseComponents(componentsCode: string): any {
    const lines: string[] = componentCodes.split('\n');

    const component: any = {
        component: '',
        props: [],
        children: [],
    };

    for (let line of lines) {
        line = line.trim();
        
        if (!line) continue;
        
        const matches = line.match(/([A-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]+)[ ]+\{/);

        // this should find the opening components
        if (matches) {
            console.log('Got a match: ', matches[1]);
        }
    }

    return components
}
```

And then I'm looking to compile into this object structure:

```json
{
    "component": "Rectangle",
    "props": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "string",
            "value": [
                {
                    "type": "assignment",
                    "value": "anId"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "children": [
        {
            "component": "Row",
            "props": [
                {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "type": "assignment",
                            "value": "id"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "backgroundColor:",
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "type": "color",
                            "value": "blue"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "children": [
                {
                    "component": "Image",
                    "props": [
                        {
                            "name": "id",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "type": "assignment",
                                    "value": "id"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "source:",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "value": "http://host.com/hello-there"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "component": "Column",
                    "props": [
                        {
                            "name": "id",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "type": "assignment",
                                    "value": "id"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "component": "Text",
                            "props": [
                                {
                                    "name": "text",
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "value": "example 1"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "component": "Text",
                            "props": [
                                {
                                    "name": "text",
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "value": "example 2"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "component": "Button",
            "props": [
                {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "type": "assignment",
                            "value": "id"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "anchors",
                    "type": "object",
                    "props": [
                        {
                            "name": "top",
                            "type": "ref",
                            "value": "row.bottom"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "left",
                            "type": "ref",
                            "value": "row.left"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "right",
                            "type": "ref",
                            "value": "row.right"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "text",
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "A Button"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What is the best practice for parsing this in the simplest way (By not writing a full blown ATS parser. This is because writing a parser is quite complex to get correct. And this code should only be relatively simple components and something that should be easily done with some regexes)